# SSH->SCP connection without password prompt on every attempt

Tags: 12.04, ssh, multiarch, scp

I would like to have a loop script run over two machines (with global IP), in which during the loop I have several scp command for  exchanging the outputs of those executions. Do we have a way to avoid password prompt on every SCPs ?  i.e., generating keys for scp, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can use key pairs like you do for ssh (scp ist "the same")

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=938969

create a rsa key pair with no password, move/copy the public part to destination machine and enjoy!